# refreshing value of textblock after RaisePropertyChanged event doesn't work

Tags: silverlight, mvvm-light

I have a simply view:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">      
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="66,66,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Text="{Binding Path=MainName,Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="66,142,0,0" Name="textBox2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Text="Space to tab :)" />
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="67,220,0,0" Name="textBox3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
</Grid>
```

And in ViewModel i have:

```
private string _mainName;

public string Name
{
    get { return MainName; }
}

public string MainName
{
    get { return _mainName; }
    set
    {
        _mainName = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(MainName);
        RaisePropertyChanged(Name);
    }
}
```

When I change value in first textbox, then `RaisePropertyChange` are called, and while debugging I see that it enters me to getters of `MainName` and `Name`, but there is no change in textblock which has binded `Name`.

Why is that, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `RaisePropertyChanged` method calls don't look right to me.  The argument should be the *name* of the property, not the *value*.   In other words, you should write

```
        RaisePropertyChanged("MainName");
        RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
```

If your properties had a type other than `string`, you'd pick the error up quite quickly, since in that case your code would not compile.